# How to correct a compile/build issue with quickfix (v1.13.3) with Python support (... "_quickfix" import exception)

Tags: python, compilation, quickfix

It took the equivalent of a 1/2 day for me to figure this out, so I want to share the Quickfix Engine compile problem I encountered and the solution.

I didn't get a reply from the "Quickfix Engine" help resources pointed to here:
"http://quickfixengine.org/help"... thus another reason I am providing this.

Environment: Fedora 18 -and- CentOS6 (64bit).

After successfully compiling quickfix with Python support (i.e. configure [opts]; make; make install), I got the following python import exception indicating that the python module, "_quickfix", could not be found:

```
==============================================
user$ python -c "import quickfix"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File " ", line 1, in
File "/home/user/APPS.d/ENTHOUGHT-PYTHON-IDE.d/x86_64.d/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix.py", line 7, in

import _quickfix
ImportError: No module named _quickfix
==============================================
```

The problem appears to be in the install script invoked by "make install".

The python interpreter is saying that the "_quickfix" module does not exit. As can be seen from the list of files install by "make install" below, there is no "_quickfix.py" file, but there is a reference to a "_quickfix.so" file and a "_quickfix.dylib" file:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_quickfix.dylib -> /home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/python/_quickfix.dylib
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_quickfix.so -> /home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/python/_quickfix.so
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix40.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix41.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix42.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix42.pyc
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix43.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix44.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix50.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix50sp1.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix50sp2.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfix.pyc
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quickfixt11.py

/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix.la
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix_python.la
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix_python.so.10.0.0
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix_python.so.10 -> libquickfix_python.so.10.0.0
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix_python.so -> libquickfix_python.so.10.0.0
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix.so.14.0.0
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix.so.14 -> libquickfix.so.14.0.0
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/libquickfix.so -> libquickfix.so.14.0.0
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/pkgconfig/quickfix.pc
```

Comment: You should edit this to remove your answer and then put it in an answer below.  Then accept your own answer so this question does not show up in "unanswered" lists.  As a bonus, future visitors will be able to reward your answer with upvotes.  (Answer upvotes are worth more than question upvotes.)

Comment: I appreciate the advice Grant. I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Come back and mark your answer as "accepted" when the site will let you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION:
The problem is that the first two entries above, which are symbolic links, are broken.

First, the destination directory is incorrect:

```
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/python/...
```

should actually be:

```
/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/...
```

So we fix that first:

```
user$ cd /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
user$ rm _quickfix.so _quickfix.dylib
user$ ln -s /home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/_quickfix.so    _quickfix.so
user$ ln -s /home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib/_quickfix.dylib _quickfix.dylib
```

Next, with destination directory location corrected, the symbolic links are still broken; this time because the file names that they point to in that (just corrected) destination directory don't exist (i.e. "_quickfix.so" and "_quickfix.dylib" don't exist).

After playing around a little, I got things to work by creating those missing files like so:

```
user$ cd /home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib
user$ ln -s libquickfix_python.so _quickfix.so
user$ ln -s <???> _quickfix.dylib  # Actually I didn't create this one yet. It's not yet clear to me what it should point to. I Will update this post later.
```

-

```
Note: Because I compiled QuickFix so that it does not install to the traditional "/usr/local/" directory structure, I had to append my "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to include: "/home/user/APPS.d/QUICKFIX.d/latest/lib"
```

With minimal testing, things seem to work now (or at least in the right direction):

```
user$ python -c "import quickfix"; echo ${?}
0
user$ python -c "import quickfix42"; echo ${?}
0
```

When I figure out what the second link should be (if it is necessary), or if I should encounter any run-time errors with the corrections I implemented, I'll update/edit this post.

I hope this helps someone.

Noel

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in Ubuntu 13.04. configured with python support and used the default destination (/usr/local/...). After successful compilation then worked out a similar solution with the following steps;

1. Create missing files/symlinks;

   cd /usr/local/lib

   sudo ln -s libquickfix_python.so _quickfix.so

   sudo ln -s _quickfix.so _quickfix.dylib
2. Change/update existing symlinks to new location:

   cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/_quickfix.so _quickfix.so

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/_quickfix.so _quickfix.dylib
3. Add new library path

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}/usr/local/lib

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create multiple symlinks - you only need to remove the bad symlinks and create one new symlink for _quickfix.so for everything to work:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_quickfix.dylib
rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_quickfix.so
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libquickfix_python.dylib /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_quickfix.so
```

This is on OS X. For Linux you will need to use the following (as the dylib extension is OS X specific)

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libquickfix_python.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_quickfix.so
```