# QuickFIX Python Binding Issue - SSL - MacOS

Tags: python, ssl, quickfix

I'm reaching out because I've encountered an issue while trying to use the QuickFIX library in my Python project, and I could use some guidance.

Objective:
I aim to use the QuickFIX library in my Python project, specifically utilizing the SSLSocketAcceptorBase class.

Steps Taken:

1. Cloned the QuickFIX GitHub repository from https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/tree/master.
2. Downloaded and extracted the QuickFIX source code.
3. Ran the `./configure` script with the `--enable-python` option to enable Python support.
4. Compiled and installed QuickFIX using `sudo make install`.
5. Checked the installed files and verified the presence of QuickFIX files in `path_repo/src/python3`:

```
CMakeLists.txt 
quickfix40.py
quickfix50sp2.py
Makefile 
quickfix41.py
quickfix_fields.py
Makefile.am 
quickfix42.py
quickfixt11.py
Makefile.in
quickfix43.py
spec
QuickfixPython.cpp
quickfix44.py
test
QuickfixPython.h
quickfix50.py
test.sh
quickfix.py
quickfix50sp1.py
```

And when I try to import quickfix, the message is:

> import _quickfix
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_quickfix'

The environment is a MacBook Pro M1 Pro running macOS 14.1.2 (23B92).

Could there be compatibility issues with the Python version (3.11.6) or the environment (MacBook Pro M1 Pro, macOS 14.1.2)?
I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance you can provide to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome, Nico. There is a number of seemingly similar questions here (e.g. [correct a compile/build issue with quickfix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15977813/21350362)). Do they have any useful recipes?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, no :(